# ShowAlertDialog Flutter Render Bug

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a problem which i have been trying to solve for the last 3 hours but it's pointless.

Now get to the point, I'm making an custom CupertinoDialog, everything looks good to me. Idk why is this happening. I've try multiple method on Stackoverflow but it's pointless. I hope someone can save me from this bug.

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIntrinsicWidth#b0789 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SimpleDialog file:///D:/FlutterProject/airchecker/lib/main.dart:50:29
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1930:12)
#3      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:21)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#6      RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: _RenderInkFeatures#383cc relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(280.0<=w<=331.4, 0.0<=h<=561.6)
...  size: MISSING
RenderObject: _RenderInkFeatures#383cc relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(280.0<=w<=331.4, 0.0<=h<=561.6)
  size: MISSING
...  child: RenderIntrinsicWidth#b0789 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: <none> (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(280.0<=w<=331.4, 0.0<=h<=561.6)
...    size: MISSING
...    stepWidth: 56.0
...    stepHeight: null
...    child: RenderConstrainedBox#9892a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: <none>
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(280.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...      child: RenderFlex#bca83 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        direction: vertical
...        mainAxisAlignment: start
...        mainAxisSize: min
...        crossAxisAlignment: stretch
...        verticalDirection: down
...        child 1: RenderPadding#27dc0 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...          parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...          padding: EdgeInsets(24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 0.0)
...          textDirection: ltr
...        child 2: RenderRepaintBoundary#dda4c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.loose
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...          usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
====================================================================================================
```

Here's my code:

```
  void showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, String title, String content) {
    showCupertinoDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (builder) => SimpleDialog(
        title: title.text.semiBold.make().centered(),
        children: [
          content.text.make().centered().expand(),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 100,
                child: OutlinedButton(
                  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1.0), // HERE
                      ),
                      side:
                      BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1.0)), // AND HERE
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: 'Cancel'.text.color(Colors.red).make(),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100,
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: 'OK'.text.white.make().px(15),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            showAlertDialog(context, "tit", "Content");
          },
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: MyClip(),
            child: Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 300,
              color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `content.text.make().centered().expand()`? what extensions are you using?

Comment: i'm using velocity_x, it's very useful

Comment: tried to use (just for test) `Text(content)` instead of `content.text.make().centered().expand(),` ? (and the same for `title:`)

Comment: Oh thank you :D i didn't know that was the problem, it actually worked xD

Comment: so velocity_x, is not SO very useful ;-)

Comment: indeed, relying on it was a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nobody,

As pskink mentioned, try to use `Text(content)`, I just replaced

```
title: title.text.semiBold.make().centered()
```

for

```
title: Text(title)
```

and

```
content.text.make().centered().expand()
```

for

```
Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [Text(content)],)
```

and it works, I've never used velocity_x, but it seems that's the problem